# populate 2d array with odd numbers java

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I need to populate a 2d array with odd numbers.

I want it to look like this

```
13579
13579
13579
13579
```

This is what I have so far:

```
    public static void twoDArray(){

    //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11243774/how-to-automatically-populate-a-2d-array-with-numbers
    int twoDimention[][] = new int[5][3];

    for(int i=0; i<twoDimention.length; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<twoDimention[i].length; j++){
            twoDimention[i][j] = 2*i + 1;


            System.out.printf("%d5", twoDimention[i][j]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

It prints:

```
1515151515
3535353535
5555555555
7575757575
9595959595
```

Can someone help make this work?

Comment: And what does JavaScript have to do with this? Do you realize they have no relationship?

Answer (score 1):

```
twoDimention[i][j] = 2*j + 1; // j instead of i
System.out.print(twoDimention[i][j]);
```

Answer (score 1):

`%d5` probably doesn't do what you think. It represents `%d` and `5` literal. If you wanted to reserve 5 characters for digit like `____2` then you need `%5d` (but IMO it is too much, simple `"%3d"` or if you don't want to add any padding `"%d"` should be fine).

So this should explain existence of `5` in `1515151515`.

That printed value also suggests that values generated for first row are `1` `1` `1` `1` `1`. It happens because you are using `i` instead of `j`. If you change your

```
twoDimention[i][j] = 2*i + 1;
```

to

```
twoDimention[i][j] = 2*j + 1;
```

you will generate `1` `3` `5` `7` `9`.

Comment: O thanks to point it out! I really was getting crazy to understand why the first row was not 1 1 1 1  1 xD